# How to refresh the page after 'event delete' in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In my calendar page, i am using delete condition to delete the event. I do not know how to refresh the page in fullcalendar so that the event deleted will disappear

Again, http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/removed/refresh/ shows that,"refresh method is removed in version1.3",But i have downloaded version 1.7. Is that supported still?. If so how should i use refresh after a event deletion is done.

Comment: Yea, but they have also added 2 other options - **[Rerender Events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/)** and **[Refetch Events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/refetchEvents/)** which basically means `refresh` right? Have you tried that?

Comment: No am not aware, Are they same?

Comment: In addition, http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/removeEvents/ should remove the event from the screen immediately, without the need to refresh.

Comment: @K48, Just post an answer to remove the duplicated events in my other question pls